# How change characters in every subtring of a string?

Tags: python, string

Suppose there is a string 'FFFBBFFBBFFBBFFBFFBFF' and in the solution there should neither “FFF” nor “BBB” in a processed string.
So my logic was to make a substrings of 3 of main string
then for each substring count the occurrence of of FF or BB if FF is greater then 2 or BB is greater then 2 then replace FF with BF or BB with BF

Iteration over substrings and then change in it.

```
for each in split_string:
     if each.count('FF') >= 2 :
         updated = each.replace('FF','BF')
```

Could not get the rest of substrings.

Comment: Hi. Share the actual input, the expected output and explain what is wrong with the current code.

Comment: input for the string is

Comment: Input for string is [FFBFBFFFBFFBFFFBB] the resulted string should not be like this FFFBBB not more then three identical charcter

Comment: If you have `string = "FFBFBFFFBFFBFFFBB"`, isn't what you need just `string.replace("FFF", "BFF")`?

Comment: Please put all the information *in your question*.

Comment: @not_speshal It should not be consectuive . String can be of any lenght consisting of any 2 charcter . The charcter should not be FFF or BBB in any part of string

Comment: @martineau Suppose there is a string "FFFFFFFBBBFFBFBFFFBBBBB" 
 Neither “FFF”  nor “BBB” may occur in a processed string

Comment: What is in `split_string` variable? Note that string are immutable which means you can't change them — so `each.replace()` is a returning a new string, which you assign to `updated` but never do anything with that value afterwards.

Comment: Print(updated + each ) it print some other value  it changes only on one substring  and could not print the rest of sub strings .

Comment: split _strings are substrings  it divide the strings into 3  that every string contains 3 element of strings.

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre] (MRE).

Answer (score 0):

You did not define rigorously the rules for the problem, so I took some liberty. But look at the fourth algorithm, it is an honest attempt.

```py
TEST_SENTENCE = "FFFBBFFBBFFBBFFBFFBFF"


def oracle(sentence: str) -> bool:
    forbidden_sequences = ("FFF", "BBB")
    return forbidden_sequences[0] not in sentence and forbidden_sequences[1] not in sentence


# Let's try some algorithms :

# -------------------------------------
def algo1(sentence: str) -> str:
    """the lazy solution"""
    return ""


result = algo1(TEST_SENTENCE)
print(f"algo1: {result!r}")  # ''
assert oracle(result)


# -------------------------------------
def algo2(sentence: str) -> str:
    """the rule-bending solution"""
    return "!" * len(sentence)


result = algo2(TEST_SENTENCE)
print(f"algo2: {result!r}")  # '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'
assert oracle(result)


# -------------------------------------
def algo3(sentence: str) -> str:
    """the check-only-the-length solution"""
    times, is_odd = divmod(len(sentence), 2)
    return "BF" * times + ("B" if is_odd else "")


result = algo3(TEST_SENTENCE)
print(f"algo3: {result!r}")  # 'BFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFBFB'
assert oracle(result)


# -------------------------------------
def algo4(sentence: str) -> str:
    """a real solution at last !"""
    b_count = sentence.count("B")
    f_count = sentence.count("F")
    if b_count == f_count:
        # simple, just alternate
        return algo3(sentence)
    else:
        # generalize to X's and Y's, with count(X) > count(Y)
        if f_count > b_count:
            x, y = "F", "B"
            x_count, y_count = f_count, b_count
        else:
            x, y = "B", "F"
            x_count, y_count = b_count, f_count

        # compute how many more X's there is than Y's
        assert x_count < 2 * y_count + 2, f"unsolvable (too many {x}'s)"
        if x_count > 2 * y_count:  # all X's will be left-saturated
            runs_two_for_one = y_count
            runs_one_for_one = 0
            tail_length = x_count - 2*y_count
        else:  # some X's will be left-insaturated
            runs_two_for_one = x_count - y_count
            runs_one_for_one = y_count - runs_two_for_one
            tail_length = 0

        xxy = x + x + y
        xy = x + y
        return xxy * runs_two_for_one + xy * runs_one_for_one + x * tail_length


does_not_contain_three_letters_runs = oracle
def oracle(original: str, solution: str) -> bool:
    """a real oracle !"""
    return does_not_contain_three_letters_runs(solution) \
           and len(original) == len(solution) \
           and (original.count("F"), original.count("B")) == (solution.count("F"), solution.count("B"))


result = algo4(TEST_SENTENCE)
print(f"algo4: {result!r}")  # 'FFBFFBFFBFFBFFBFBFBFB'
assert oracle(TEST_SENTENCE, result)
```

The next step is to find an optimal solution (the minimal edit distance from the original sentence), but that is a bit tricky.

Comment: For the lulz, I made a fifth algo : `import itertools; return "".join(next(candidate for candidate in itertools.permutations(sentence, len(sentence)) if does_not_contain_three_letters_runs("".join(candidate))))` but its exponential time complexity starts to bite at >=13 letters.

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, this could be the solution. Same procedure with the replacement of BB or BBB.

```
split_string = ["FFFFFBBBBB","FFFF","FFFFFFFBBBFFBFBFFFBBBBB","FFFBBFFBBFFBBFFBFFBFF", "FFFAFF", "FACABF"]

for index,each in enumerate(split_string):
    # new_string_2 = each.replace("FF", "FB")
    for i in range(2):
        new_string = each.replace("FFF", "FBF")
        new_string_2 = new_string.replace("BBB", "BFB")
        each = new_string_2
    split_string[index] = new_string_2

print(split_string)
```

Comment: "FFFFFFFBBBFFBFBFFFBBBBB" Neither “FFF” nor “BBB” may occur in a processed string  how can this can handle the situation for BBB should we add the one more condition?

Comment: Yes. If we also replace the BBB to BFB there can occur an other problem.
So i just added a loop. Because the example "FFFFFBBBBB" would be changed to "FBFFFBFBBB". So we have to do this two times.

All in all, i think it's not the most effective way to do it. but it works

Comment: Thank you  i did not look at the index value when i was trying. why you kept the range at 2?

Comment: you also can change it to a higher value. but i think that's the maximum number of loops you need to get rid of all "FFF"'s and "BBB"s.

Example:
if there are 5 same letters in a row: "FFFFF" --> "FBFFF"-->FBFBF"
and if there are more than 5 same letters in a row:
"FFFFFF" (start)
"FBFFBF"(after first loop; no more occurrence of the same three letters)